# Missing project subtype F# project

Tags: f#

I try to load a F# project with Visual basic 2011 beta and I have the following issue, which appears for the first time :

```
There is a missing project subtype.
Subtype: '{5B89FCC2-C9F6-49a8-8F8D-EDDCC3FDC9E9}' is unsupported by this installation
```

Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point (VS2010?) you installed the [FsProjectExtender](http://fsprojectextender.codeplex.com/) to get some extra functionality available to F# projects in Visual Studio. Just re-install that extension again for VS2011 and you should be OK, or remove the dependency in the `.fsproj` file as noted by @Brian.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that guid is for (Bing search did not turn up much), so you might simply try removing it from the `ProjectTypeGuids` in the `.fsproj` file (leaving only `f2a71f9b-5d33-465a-a702-920d77279786` which is for the F# project system).